# Run bash script from pydroid inbuilt terminal. Install miniconda on Android. Access sdcard from UserLAnd

Tags: python, android, django, bash, pydroid

chd.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
cd django/hellodjango
exec bash
python manage.py runserver
```

chd.py

```
# a=`python chd.py`;cd $a
import os
new_dir = "django/hellodjango"
os.chdir(new_dir)
```

are the two ways I have tried.
Also, on terminal I have tried,

```
.  chd.sh

./chd.sh

. ./chd.sh
```

I have also tried to assign to variable and then run on terminal but no success.
Spent over 4 hours trying multiple methods given on stackoverflow.com but no success yet.
The only thing that has worked yet is,

```
alias mycd='cd django/hellodjango'
```

But I will have to copy paste it everytime.

```
alias myrun = `cd django/hellodjango && python manage.py runserver`
```

And,

```
alias myrun = `cd django/hellodjango; python manage.py runserver`
```

doesn't work.
This is just a sample, there are so many django commands that I have to use repeatedly. Appreciate if you have read all this way.
If you know the link where this is discussed, please attach the link, as I was not able to find after hours of search.
Edit:

```
 /storage/emulated/0 $
```

This is what the prompt appears like.

```
/storage/emulated/0/django/hellodjango
```

This is the path.

```
/storage/emulated/0 $ cd django/hellodjango
/storage/emulated/0/django/hellodjango $ python manage.py 
runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 25, 2020 - 19:08:42
Django version 3.0.7, using settings 'hellodjango.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Individually works fine.

Edit:

> /storage/emulated/0 $ chmod u+x chd.sh /storage/emulated/0 $ chmod u+x
> rn.sh /storage/emulated/0 $ ./chd.sh ./chd.sh: cd: line 2: can't cd t:
> No such file or directory /storage/emulated/0 $ chmod u+x chd.py
> /storage/emulated/0 $ a=`python chd.py`;cd $a
> ~/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/app_HOME $

Edit:

> /data/user/0/tech.ula/files/support/dbclient: Caution, skipping
> hostkey check for localhost
>
> subham@localhost's password:
> subham@localhost:~$ ls
> subham@localhost:~$ cd
> subham@localhost:~$ pwd
> /home/subham
> subham@localhost:~$ pkg install miniconda

> -bash: pkg: command not found
> subham@localhost:~$ apt install miniconda
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done

> E: Unable to locate package miniconda
> subham@localhost:~$

> subham@localhost:~$ cd ..
> subham@localhost:/home$ cd ..
> subham@localhost:/$ ls

> bin   dev   host-rootfs  mnt   root  srv
> sys  var boot  etc   lib          opt   run   storage  tmp data  home
> media        proc  sbin  support  usr
> subham@localhost:/$ cd ..

> subham@localhost:/$ cd sys
> subham@localhost:/sys$ ls

> ls: cannot open
> directory '.': Permission denied

> subham@localhost:/sys$ cd..

> -bash: cd..: command not found
> subham@localhost:/sys$ cd ..

> subham@localhost:/$ cd storage

> subham@localhost:/storage$ ls internal
> subham@localhost:/storage$ cd internal
> subham@localhost:/storage/internal$ ls
> subham@localhost:/storage/internal$ ls -l total 0
> subham@localhost:/storage/internal$ cd 0

> -bash: cd: 0: No such file or directory subham@localhost:/storage/internal$

```
subham@localhost:/$ chmod -R 777 /host-rootfs
chmod: changing permissions of '/host-rootfs': Read-only file system
chmod: cannot read directory '/host-rootfs': Permission denied
subham@localhost:/$
```

https://github.com/CypherpunkArmory/UserLAnd/issues/46

Comment: Have no idea what a *pydroid inbuilt terminal* is, but wrt the bash script, the line after `exec bash` is not even read unless no executable named `bash` is found in the directories listed in PATH and the script is sourced from an interactive shell, and wrt the python script, changing the directory for the python process won't change the directory for the shell that invokes it.

Comment: Did you `chmod u+x` chd.sh and chd.py?

Comment: @l3l_aze made changes posted as edit the output error

Comment: [Possibly related Q?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4256107/7665043), especially [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/7665043) which details running Bash code from Python. Also, this is just kind of a weak terminal. UserLAnd or another chroot Linux environment would be closer to full functionality, even Termux.

Comment: @l3l_aze tried UserLAnd but getting following error. How do I navigate to the files chd.sh or chd.py

Comment: The UserLAnd-specific `/host-rootfs/` maps to Android's root folder, `/`. So, internal storage should be available from `/host-rootfs` at `/storage/emulated/0`, `/sdcard` (a symlink to /storage/emulated/0`), or `/mnt/sdcard` (another symlink). The rest depends on where your files for your project are from there, but in your above edits it looks like they're directly in `/sdcard/`. There are pre-packaged anaconda/miniconda installers on their site for installation, and you can download them in your browser and access them in `host-rootfs/sdcard/Downloads/`.

Comment: Changing what you're using may have been a bad idea, as it seems to be just making everything more complex. I'm sorry. You may need to rewrite the question title + content to explain what you're trying to do rather than what you're having a problem doing. As it's gotten pretty messed up you could possibly have this closed and post a new question instead.

Comment: subham@localhost:/host-rootfs/storage/emulated/0$ 
    chd.sh-bash: chd.sh: command not found
    subham@localhost:/host-rootfs/storage/emulated/0$ . chd.sh
    -bash: chd.sh: Permission denied
    subham@localhost:/host-rootfs/storage/emulated/0$chmod u+x chd.sh
    subham@localhost:/host-rootfs/storage/emulated/0$chmod u+x chd.py
    subham@localhost:/host-rootfs/storage/emulated/0$chd.sh-bash: chd.sh: command not found
    subham@localhost:/host-rootfs/storage/emulated/0$bash chd.sh
    bash: chd.sh: Permission denied

Comment: >subham@localhost:/host-rootfs/storage/emulated/0/django$ chmod u+x Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86.sh >subham@localhost:/host-rootfs/storage/emulated/0/django$ bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86.sh bash: Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86.sh: Permission denied >subham@localhost:/host-rootfs/storage/emulated/0/django$

Comment: @l3l_aze installing desktop environment hasn't helped much either